# Expand a tuple TYPE into a variadic template?

Tags: c++, tuples, metaprogramming, variadic-templates, type-traits

I have a function `main_func` where I modify the paramater pack/variadic template by converting it to a tuple. After I have modified it, ex: `original = tuple<int, float, string>` becomes `modified = tuple<int float>` I want to expand the modified tuple to another function in the example `get_type_vector`so that the parameter pack represents the types of the modified tuple `Args = int, float`.

```cpp
template<typename... Args>
void main_func()
{
    // Modify the parameter pack (which if im correct can only be done by converting to tuple?)
    using original = std::tuple<Args...>;
    using modified = // something that alters the types of the original tuple

    // This is what i want to accomplish
    // somehow expand the tuple type like a parameter pack
    auto vec = get_type_vector<modified...>()
}

// Returns a vector of type_info
template<typename... Args>
std::vector<type_info> get_type_vector()
{
    return { type_info<Args>()... };
}
```

Is it possible to somehow expand a tuple type like the type of a parameter pack? I have found examples using `std::apply` etc. but that requires you to have a value and not just the typedef of a tuple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can expand a tuple easily by introducing a layer of indirection, which could be a lambda (C++20) or template function (C++11). E.g.

```
std::tuple<int, float, char> t;
[]<typename... Ts>(std::tuple<Ts...>)
{
    // use `Ts...` here
}(t);
```

In your case:

```
template <typename T>
struct type_wrapper { using type = T; };

template<typename... Args>
std::vector<type_info> get_type_vector(type_wrapper<std::tuple<Args...>>)
{
    return { type_info<Args>()... };
}

get_type_vector(type_wrapper<std::tuple<int, float, char>>{});
```

The `type_wrapper` class prevents useless instantiations of tuples at run-time. You can use `std::type_identity` in C++20.

Answer (score 2):

A fairly simple approach would be to just overload and let the compiler deduce the types. [`std::type_identity`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_identity) can be useful here (C++20, but easily reproduced in any version of C++). It can create simple cheap tags out of types

```
template<typename... Args>
std::vector<type_info> get_type_vector(std::type_identity<std::tuple<Args...>>)
{
    return { type_info<Args>()... };
}
```

To use it is to write

```
auto vec = get_type_vector(std::type_identity<modified>{})
```